# Extend an abstract class that extends another abstract class and need to override the interface the parent abstract class implements

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I have an entity class called Post. Post's parent is based on an abstract class called AbstractPost. AbstractPost has a variable "author" who's setter's signature is defined in an interface called PostInterface.

I am in a situtation where I need to override the author's setters, but don't want to modify the parents (ofcourse).

These are the parent classes:

```
class Post extends AbstractPost
abstract class AbstractPost implements PostInterface
interface PostInterface
```

I have the following classes:

```
class MyPost extends MyAbstractPost
abstract class MyAbstractPost extends AbstractPost implements MyPostInterface
interface MyPostInterface extends PostInterface
```

However, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of MyAbstractPost::setAuthor() must be
>   compatible with that of PostInterface::setAuthor()

I've read that children inherit the "implements" part (what is the right lingo here?) of the parent class, so I gues I want to know how to override that. Or am I not extending/implementing in the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly needs to change in the setAuthor method? You're getting that error because you defined the method signature in the interface and your other class isn't implementing the method correctly. Can you post the code within the interface and abstract class mentioned in the error message?

Comment: You can't. if you have -- which is a design smell -- you will need to introduce a new proxy method.

Comment: @delete-me-please Ok and how would I do that?

Comment: @delete-me-please: about the design: the creator of the parent class defines the author as a string. However I want it to be a user_id. I wouldn't know of any other way to accomplish this (except for leaving the author field empty, which is weird imho)

Comment: A proxy method is like any other method, you just call the 'actual method' whiten your method after applying the necessary changes, you have not provided enough of information about your design for me or anyone else to give you an exact solution.

Comment: @ThomasK So, how do you define YOUR MyAbstractPost::setAuthor(...) 
What is YOUR parameter type?

Comment: @GermannArlington: I define it like so: public function `setAuthor(SiteBundle\Entity\User $author = null)` while the signature of the parent interface is `public function setAuthor($author);`

Comment: @ThomasK ??? Your interface does NOT define parameter or return types? The only reason for your error (that I can think of) is if you attempt to use the same signature (name and parameters types) but change return type at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Overloading the method signature defeats the purpose of having an interface.